# When is nextval evaluated in transactional writes?

Tags: postgresql, sequence

If I have a sequence 'foo' in postgres, and do something like the following:

```
begin;
insert into ... values (nextval('foo'));
commit;
```

Is `nextval` evaluated on commit? In other words, if I only do such writes to that column, will it be visible as monotonically increasing, or is there a race there?

The docs make very clear that sequences are non-transactional, but not whether they could be used to order writes this way.

If yes, what about this?

```
begin;
select nextval('foo'); -- save the value
insert into ... values (<saved value>);
commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

`nextval` is executed immediately. Every call to `nextval` is guaranteed to return a unique number, even if several statements call it on the same sequence at the same time.

Nothing can go wrong with sequences!

Comment: So there is a race with transactions, then?

Comment: No, sequences are specifically designed for that. As soon as you call `nextval`, you get a unique vakue, and that value is never reused.

Comment: But if two transactions are writing a sequence value, there's no guarantee the transaction ordering will be the same as the sequence ordering, right? If two concurrent transactions write `nextval`, is it always the highest that wins?

Comment: I don't quite understand. No transaction *writes* `nextval`. Whenever `nextval` is executed, a counter is increased and the value returned. Very simple. If the transaction then takes its time, a transaction that called `nextval` later may use a higher value earlier. If a transaction rolls back, the sequence value is lost. I have the feeling that you are missing some crucial point here, but I cannot put my finger on what is missing.

Comment: My question is just this: if two transactions do `begin; insert nextval(); commit;`, can the transaction with the lower sequence value win? I think your last comment answered it, but not the answer :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "win"? I think we have to be precise here to avoid misunderstandings.